# Firestore warning on filtering with positional arguments. How to use 'filter' kwarg in Firestore queries?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore started showing

```
UserWarning: Detected filter using positional arguments. Prefer using the 'filter' keyword argument instead.
```

when using `query.where(field_path, op_string, value)` while it's the the method from the official docs https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries

So how shall we use the 'filter' kwarg? Couldn't find docs or samples on that.

**UPDATE:**
there is an open issue on this on GitHub https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/705
(with no reaction from Google folks)

**UPDATE2:**
so, basically, it should look like this

```
from google.cloud.firestore import CollectionReference
from google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_query import FieldFilter, BaseCompositeFilter

...

conditions = [[field, operator, value], [field, operator, value], ...]
query = CollectionReference(path1, path2, path3, ...)

query = query.where(filter=BaseCompositeFilter('AND', [FieldFilter(*_c) for _c in conditions]))
```

For a FieldFilter operator usual ==, !=, etc. work as specified here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators

Instead of 'AND' you could also use 'OPERATOR_UNSPECIFIED', but I'm not sure if it does what I think it should https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery#Operator

Comment: seeing these new warnings too

Comment: and as \_\_doc\_\_ says, it raises when 
"* Both the positional arguments and the keyword argument `filter` were passed."

Comment: that's the ValueError "Can't pass in both the positional arguments and 'filter' at the same time", and it stops the execution

query.where() allows both positional and kwargs, but with positional it started firing the UserWarning. Looks like Firestore is moving on to kwargs, but forgot to update the docs.

Comment: there is an open issue on it on Github https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/705

Comment: Your **UPDATE2** snippet `BaseCompositeFilter('AND',...)` won't work. Instead, you need `BaseCompositeFilter(StructuredQuery.CompositeFilter.Operator.AND,...)` where `from google.cloud.firestore_v1.types import StructuredQuery`. The `AND` isn't a string; rather, it is an `Enum` defined at https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/blob/dd977226ef95420e22bd51e1073c7a0878a3da93/google/cloud/firestore_v1/types/query.py#L259

Comment: @VincentYin it actually works. The line is the exact copy from my module.

Comment: OK, @syldman. I cannot understand how your original code reconciles with the `Enum` I pointed out in Google source code. Anyway, neither your code nor my code produced the correct query result for me. So, I don't know what's wrong. Also, GCP docs at https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#compound_and_queries don't use that `BaseCompositeFilter` at all; rather, it uses a chained `where()` which works for me. In fact, I cannot find any examples (except your snippet above) on the internet of how to use `BaseCompositeFilter` (with all the necessary `import` statements.)

Comment: @VincentYin can you show your code? 'AND' is the key to get Operator Enum value

Comment: chained where() works too, but it gets complicated if the number of conditions is dynamic

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on `@Robert G`'s [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76156390/9642) you can get rid of this warning with a semi-small tweak.

Instead of:

```py
query = collection_ref
query = query.where(field, op, value)
```

Do this:

```py
from google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_query import FieldFilter
query = collection_ref
query = query.where(filter=FieldFilter(field, op, value))
```

And then the warning disappears. Hope this helps!

Comment: accepting this, although it lacks an example which is very much necessary given that Google 'forgot' to include one in their documentation

Comment: and for multiple conditions it should be the CompositeFilter https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery#compositefilter

Comment: The usage of FieldFilter already appears in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

Answer (score 2):

As previously posted in the comments, there's an ongoing issue currently posted in Github. For those who experience similar issues, they could check this [Github link](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/705) for updates regarding the issue.

In addition, you could also file for a bug so that Google Devs/Engineers could also check on this and provide immediate solutions/fixes.

You could file a bug through these links:

- [Issue tracking system and product feature requests](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)
- [Firebase bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs)

Answer (score 1):

For multiple conditions

```
from google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_query import FieldFilter
from google.cloud.firestore_v1.base_query import BaseCompositeFilter
query = collection_ref
query = query.where(filter = BaseCompositeFilter("AND",[FieldFilter(field1,op1,value1),FieldFilter(field2,op2,value2)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem with the Datastore variant, you can get rid of this error doing this:

```
filters = [('property', '=', 'val')]
query = client.query(kind='MyKind', filters=filters)
```

This is indeed documented, but not in the online documentation. It can be found introspecting **datastore > client.py** , line 809

Comment: I tested with this answer and still got the same `UserWarning`

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same problem with datastore, you can resolve the warning by using `google.cloud.datastore.query.PropertyFilter(property_name, operator, value)`([docs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/datastore/latest/queries#class-googleclouddatastorequerypropertyfilterpropertyname-operator-value)). The code snippet would be the following:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
from google.cloud.datastore.query import PropertyFilter

query = datastore.Client().query(kind="MyKind")
query.add_filter(filter=PropertyFilter("property", "=", value))
```